# How to verify with Adafruit_Fingerprint.h if the fingerprint exists and enrolar with this?

Tags: arduino, fingerprint

I have the problem that I need to verify a fingerprint before being registered, my problem is that I have to put my finger on the fingerprint 3 times, which I prefer to do only twice that is normal. The verification is good, I just don't know why I have to remove my finger to continue with the registration of this one, which I do in the `getFingerprintEnroll ()` method.

My expectation is to place the finger on the sensor for the first time, here I verify that the fingerprint does not exist, in case it is not registered, make the first capture of it for registration without having to remove the finger from the sensor and the rest doesn't matter anymore.

In my `loop` i have something like:

```
id = readnumber();
// ...
while ((huella = finger.getImage()) != FINGERPRINT_OK);
if (getFingerprintIDez() != -1) {
    Serial.println("exist");
    return;  
} else {
    Serial.println("no_exist");  
    while (!  getFingerprintEnroll() );
}
```

My methods used are:

```
int getFingerprintIDez() {
    uint8_t p = huella;
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    p = finger.image2Tz();
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
    if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;
    return finger.fingerID; 
}

uint8_t getFingerprintEnroll() {
  int p = -1;
  while (p != FINGERPRINT_OK) {
    p = finger.getImage(); // Here it is paused until I remove my finger
  }
  //...
}
```

Originally posted in Spanish [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294736/como-verificar-con-adafruit-fingerprint-h-si-la-huella-existe-y-enrrolar-con-las)

Comment: pass the `huella` variable into the other functions so you dont have to call getimage again

Comment: how do I do that? because something like that I tried

Answer (score 1):

To have good performance on matching fingerprints ([FRR & FAR](https://www.bayometric.com/false-acceptance-rate-far-false-recognition-rate-frr/)), enrollment process need to capture multiple times same finger to consolidate list of [minutiae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint) (It works as this on iOS or Android for instance).

On adafruit SDK you could setup security level:
False Acceptance Rate: <0.001% (Security level 3)
False Reject Rate: <1.0% (Security level 3)
Maybe this will change number of time need to put finger for enrollment (depends on SDK).

In your case, I suggest you to:

1. Before enrollment capture finger to check not already exists
2. Start enrollment with multiple capture

Comment: Do not give a solution, and that was tried as expressed in the code